# EF Lazy loading returns null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We are facing a problem on EF.
While **lazy loading**, **sometimes** the navigation property is returning null.

Note: I made `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;` on the db context

**Model:**

```
public class Student
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public Int64 Address_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Address_Id")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Database access:**

```
Student oStudnet = context.Students.FirstOrDefault();
Int64 addressId= oStudnet.Address.Id
```

"null exception" on "oStudnet.Address.id"  // Address is null here

Comment: I am afraid your code here is oversimplified and the actual reason that this happens is omitted as a result. As of the code posted here, this should not happen (well, I am pretty sure you think the same :) ) Could you please provide a bit more context? For example, maybe you are using the `.AsNoTracking()` extension somewhere explicitly or hidden by another helper that you've written.

Comment: [Log the generated SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework) and check it against the database.

Comment: I have the same problem. I added optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies(); to Context.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) and I get 'System.InvalidOperationException' on all of my naviguation property unless I debug it step by step.

Answer (score -2):

```
Student oStudnet = context.Students.Include("Address").FirstOrDefault();
```

Then you can access the address

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Unsderstood **Include(Eager loading)** will work out.
We have the use case of **lazy loading**, i attached a sample code only.